# Adobe Flex Caching Array

Tags: arrays, apache-flex, caching, flex4.5

My program fills an array with data from a facebook page feed but every time i go from one tab to another it wants to reload this data, is there any way i can cache this array so that it will not reload the information unless its changed?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly why your Views should not contain Service logic.  Instead, your View should dispatch an event asking for the service call and your Controller (you do have one, right?) should catch that event and decide whether to act on it or not.

Comment: not sure what you mean by a Controller, do you mean a separate AS file with the code that the view will call when loaded?

Comment: No, I mean something at a higher level that is responsible for propogating changes asked for by the View into the Model and making any changes necessary to the View that you're not handling via data binding (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller).  If you don't already have a MVC architecture in place, Robotlegs is a good place to start, and it will teach you good habits from the beginning (http://www.robotlegs.org/). FWIW, your View should NOT know about the Controller.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know the data hasn't changed without reloading it?

Maybe what you need is to store the timestamp of the last service call, than measure the amount of time before executing the service call again.

Perhaps with a 5-minute timeout, if the user continuously changes tabs within 5-minutes from the last service call, the array persists previously loaded data.

After 5-minutes, if the user changes back to that tab the service call can fire, load data, than update the timestamp to prevent loading.